# Replace all values in every n-th column with values from different dataframe

Tags: r

I have a large data frame A with micro array data of 47323 rows and 1570 columns. I need to replace all values in every third column in data frame A with new, corrected values stored in data frame B. Therefore, I need to replace values in columns 3, 6, 9, etc. in A with values in columns 1, 2, 3, etc. from B.

The number of rows in both data frames is the same. The column names are partially matched (every third column name in data frame A and column names in data frame B).

Can anyone please point me towards right direction to solve this problem ?

My apologies for rudimentary programming question from biologist.

Comment: Might be useful to give a little subset as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this maybe?

```
cols <- seq(3, 1570, 3)
A[cols] <- B[seq(cols)]
```

This will replace column 3, 6, 9, etc in A with column 1, 2, 3, etc from B.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Sorry if I wasn't very clear... Columns 3, 6, 9 etc. in A need to be replaced with columns 1, 2, 3 etc. from B

Comment: I updated my example.

Comment: It also worked! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest:

```
#--- Example data ---
n <- 5
m1 <- 18
m2 <- 4
A <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:(n*m1),n,m1))
B <- as.data.frame(outer(rep(-100,5)-(1:n),1:m2))
A
B
#------------------------------------------------
i <- 1
k <- min(1+(ncol(A)-i) %/% 3,ncol(B))
A[,3*(1:k)+i-3] <- B[,1:k]
A
```

The columns i,i+3,i+6,... of A are replaced by the columns 1,2,3,... of B:

```
> #--- Example data ---
> n <- 5

> m1 <- 18

> m2 <- 4

> A <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:(n*m1),n,m1))

> B <- as.data.frame(outer(rep(-100,5)-(1:n),1:m2))

> A
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
1  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41  46  51  56  61  66  71  76  81  86
2  2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42  47  52  57  62  67  72  77  82  87
3  3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43  48  53  58  63  68  73  78  83  88
4  4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44  49  54  59  64  69  74  79  84  89
5  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90

> B
    V1   V2   V3   V4
1 -101 -202 -303 -404
2 -102 -204 -306 -408
3 -103 -206 -309 -412
4 -104 -208 -312 -416
5 -105 -210 -315 -420

> #------------------------------------------------
> i <- 1

> k <- min(1+(ncol(A)-i) %/% 3,ncol(B))

> A[,3*(1:k)+i-3] <- B[,1:k]

> A
    V1 V2 V3   V4 V5 V6   V7 V8 V9  V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
1 -101  6 11 -202 21 26 -303 36 41 -404  51  56  61  66  71  76  81  86
2 -102  7 12 -204 22 27 -306 37 42 -408  52  57  62  67  72  77  82  87
3 -103  8 13 -206 23 28 -309 38 43 -412  53  58  63  68  73  78  83  88
4 -104  9 14 -208 24 29 -312 39 44 -416  54  59  64  69  74  79  84  89
5 -105 10 15 -210 25 30 -315 40 45 -420  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90
>
```

If "B" has too many columns, the overhanging columns are ignored. For example, if m2=8 and i=2:

```
> #--- Example data ---
> n <- 5

> m1 <- 18

> m2 <- 8

> A <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:(n*m1),n,m1))

> B <- as.data.frame(outer(rep(-100,5)-(1:n),1:m2))

> A
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18
1  1  6 11 16 21 26 31 36 41  46  51  56  61  66  71  76  81  86
2  2  7 12 17 22 27 32 37 42  47  52  57  62  67  72  77  82  87
3  3  8 13 18 23 28 33 38 43  48  53  58  63  68  73  78  83  88
4  4  9 14 19 24 29 34 39 44  49  54  59  64  69  74  79  84  89
5  5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45  50  55  60  65  70  75  80  85  90

> B
    V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8
1 -101 -202 -303 -404 -505 -606 -707 -808
2 -102 -204 -306 -408 -510 -612 -714 -816
3 -103 -206 -309 -412 -515 -618 -721 -824
4 -104 -208 -312 -416 -520 -624 -728 -832
5 -105 -210 -315 -420 -525 -630 -735 -840

> #------------------------------------------------
> i <- 2

> k <- min(1+(ncol(A)-i) %/% 3,ncol(B))

> A[,3*(1:k)+i-3] <- B[,1:k]

> A
  V1   V2 V3 V4   V5 V6 V7   V8 V9 V10  V11 V12 V13  V14 V15 V16  V17 V18
1  1 -101 11 16 -202 26 31 -303 41  46 -404  56  61 -505  71  76 -606  86
2  2 -102 12 17 -204 27 32 -306 42  47 -408  57  62 -510  72  77 -612  87
3  3 -103 13 18 -206 28 33 -309 43  48 -412  58  63 -515  73  78 -618  88
4  4 -104 14 19 -208 29 34 -312 44  49 -416  59  64 -520  74  79 -624  89
5  5 -105 15 20 -210 30 35 -315 45  50 -420  60  65 -525  75  80 -630  90
>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why don't I get anything? My answer is more elaborate and came earlier than the corrected version of drmariod's accepted answer. How about my second answer? What am I doing wrong? )-;

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. Unfortunately, the system doesn't allow me to do so :( Both answers worked, however, I accepted drmaroid's one because for me it was easier solution to understand/modify/adapt. No offence, thanks again for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the columns in "B" match to the names of the columns in A they should replace, you can simply use

```
A[colnames(B)] <- B
```